# Set value of first option on dropdown list using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

So I am trying to populate my modal form using jquery but I can't make the dropdown list work. I am new to jquery so I am not sure if I am doing things right. This is how I passed the values to jquery using data:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editItem" data-id="<?php echo $row_selectItem['item_id'];?>" data-no="<?php echo $row_selectItem['item_no'];?>" data-desc="<?php echo $row_selectItem['item_desc'];?>" data-cat="<?php echo $row_selectItem['cat_name'];?>" data-unit="<?php echo $row_selectItem['unit_name'];?>" data-quantity="<?php echo $row_selectItem['quantity'];?>" data-cost="<?php echo $row_selectItem['unit_cost'];?>" >
```

And this is how I set the values on jquery and to show them on modal form:

```
$('#editItem').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
              var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
              var no = $(e.relatedTarget).data('no');
              var desc = $(e.relatedTarget).data('desc');
              var cat = $(e.relatedTarget).data('cat');
              var unit = $(e.relatedTarget).data('unit');
              var cost = $(e.relatedTarget).data('cost');
              var quantity = $(e.relatedTarget).data('quantity');
              $("#item_id").val(id);
              $("#item_no").val(no);
              $("#item_desc").val(desc);
              $("#category option:first").val(cat);
              $("#unit option:first").val(unit);
              $("#unit_cost").val(cost);
              $("#quantity").val(quantity);
            });

            $('#editItem').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
          $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
        })
```

The category and unit are dropdown list. That is where the previous values should be shown as first options on the dropdown list. The rest are working.

This is my code for select in modal form. I will not include the rest of them, only the select for unit and category. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" id="category" name="category">
    <option value=""></option> //value should be here
  </select>
  <span class="help-block"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" name="unit" id="unit">
    <option value=""></option>//value should be here
  </select>
  <span class="help-block"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Are the options already added in these dropdown lists and you just want them to move to the top?

Comment: @progrAmmar It's actually an update/edit form that's why I want the passed value to be the first option on the dropdown list, to show the user that it's the current value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that is your HTML code

You can try this

```
$("#category > option:first-child").val(cat);
$("#unit > option:first-child").val(unit);
```

And if you want to set the text for the option as well:

```
$("#category > option:first-child").text(cat);
$("#unit > option:first-child").text(unit);
```

If however, your select value already contains a list of options and you want to remove the selected one and add it to the top then you can do something like this

```
if($('#category > option[value=' + cat + ']').length !== 0){
    $('#category > option[value=' + cat + ']').remove();
}    
$('#category').prepend(new Option(cat, cat));
```

Comment: I edited to add another scenario as well. The val will work but you wouldn't be seeing val on screen because it's the value of the dropdown field. Remember that the option has two fields, Text and Value, the text is what you see in the list and value is what gets sent to the server as input.